# IBCocoaTouchPlugin on iPhone SDK 3.0

Tags: cocoa-touch, xcode, iphone-sdk-3.0, interface-builder, osx-snow-leopard

I had upgraded my OS into Snow Leopard, and I'm using Xcode 3.2 with iPhone SDK 3.0 for Snow Leopard.

I had cleaned up the existing Developer Tools, uninstall, and I deleted the /Developer directory, and I reinstall.

But, the problem is, Interface Builder is showing 3 pop up alerts with this message:

Assertion Message: Interface Builder encountered an error communicating with the iPhone Simulator. If you choose to file a crash report or radar for this issue, please check Console.app for crash reports for "Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool" and include their content in your crash report.

IBUIViewImageRequester failed to rasterize a UILabel, UIButton, UITextField, and UISegmentedControl.

Exception name: NSInvalidSendPortException
Exception reason: [NSMachPort sendBeforeDate:] destination port invalid
Exception backtrace: 
(null)
Exception info:(null)

Some people had experienced this, and some people were able to resolve it by copying the right IBCocoaTouchPlugin.ibplugin from those not experiencing problems.

So if anybody could share it, that would be great.

I could click continue to proceed, but it's an annoying problem.

Update:
It's caused by IB that's linking to the wrong libstdc++ in /usr/local/lib. The IB should link to libstdc++ in /usr/lib/

Just delete or move the interfering libs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's caused by IB that's linking to the wrong libstdc++ in /usr/local/lib.
The IB should link to libstdc++ in /usr/lib/

Just delete or move the interfering libs.

Comment: please help i have the same problem..however i cant find any libstdc in my usr/local/lib folder..WHat do i do? All i have are just some libfuse files

Comment: It shouldn't be in /usr/local/lib, the IB should look for these files in /usr/lib.

Comment: Ok so what libs should i delete?

Comment: Did you found it (libstdc++) in /usr/lib?

Comment: I have these three files `libstdc++.6.0.9.dylib` `libstdc++.6.dylib` `libstdc++.dylib`

Comment: Well, there shouldn't be a problem. Those files should not exist in /usr/local/lib

Comment: for some reasons it started working today...was really happy after 8months

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I moved the /usr/local to another place, and the problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

Update:  I ran into a very similar problem today.  The solution was to delete my old /Developer folder I used with Xcode prior to 4.0.